# Não é possível acessar um objeto descartado

Tags: c#, winforms, instanciar-objeto

Estou instanciando um formulário a partir de um double click em um DataGridView de outro formulário, onde através deste retorno as informações daquela linha para o formulário.

Está funcionando corretamente porém quando eu fecho esse formulário e dou novamente o double click na mesma linha ou em outra para abrir o formulário novamente eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível acessar um objeto descartado.

O código onde acontece o erro é esse:

```
 private void dgvDados_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        if (dgvDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.exibirdados.txtcnpj.Text = dgvDados.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpcadastro.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtrazao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmboperadora.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtlinhas.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbClassificacao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpvigencia.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcontrato.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbFidelidade.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtvalorgasto.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixoempresa.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtgestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcelular.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixogestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtemail.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtobs.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        }

        this.exibirdados.ShowDialog(); //aqui acontece o erro
    }
```

Código da instancia do formulário:

```
public partial class TelaInicio : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{

    internal ExibirDados exibirdados = null;

    public TelaInicio(ExibirDados exibirdados)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.exibirdados = exibirdados;
    }
```

Comment: Utilize o `new` na linha `internal ExibirDados exibirdados = new ExibirDados();`

Comment: @W.Faustino procede com o mesmo erro

Comment: Tenta criar o objeto `ExibirDados` dentro `dgvDados_CellContentDoubleClick` sem utilizar o `this.`. Sei que não vai deixar o GC limpo mas... pode funcionar bem.

Comment: @W.Faustino se eu fizer isso ele irá abrir e fechar sem erro, porém não irá recuperar as informações para o form, já que eu estou recebendo elas da instancia `exibirdados`

Comment: Cola o código todo ai! Ai fica mais fácil a gente te ajudar.

Comment: consegui resolver, em parte oque você disse estava certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O detalhe está no `this` já que estou atribuindo a recuperação das informações para a instancia `exibirdados` devo instanciar um novo objeto a partir dela, eu estava tentando instanciar a partir de um novo objeto.

Assim o form abria sem erros porém me trazia o formulário vazio, a forma correta seria essa:

```
private void dgvDados_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.exibirdados = new ExibirDados();

        if (dgvDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.exibirdados.txtcnpj.Text = dgvDados.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpcadastro.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtrazao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmboperadora.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtlinhas.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbClassificacao.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.dtpvigencia.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcontrato.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.cmbFidelidade.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtvalorgasto.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixoempresa.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtgestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtcelular.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtfixogestor.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtemail.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            this.exibirdados.txtobs.Text = dgvDados.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        }

        this.exibirdados.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza ok.
mas acho que você esta excluindo o form que abre com os dados após a primeira exibição e tentando exibir um objeto que já foi excluido na segunda tentativa de exibição.

tentativa de solução:
instanciar um novo objeto de exibição sempre ao executar o evento de click e atribuir os novos dados apos a instancia do mesmo.